# how to swap a string from one index to a different index?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, swap

This is my code so far I am not sure how to take the indices of a list `[fish, chips, sauce, plate]` and put `chips` at index  `plate` is.

```
class Names{
      ArrayList<String> list;

public Names()
{
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**    precondition:    p and q represent indexes of existing elements in the list array.
  *      postcondition:  the elements, represented by p and q, have swapped locations.
      */
public void swapNames(int p, int q){      
      temp = p;
      p = q;
      q = temp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `p` and `q` are valid indexes in the given array list, `ArrayList`'s methods [`get(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) and [`set(int i, E obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) can be used to efficiently swap the elements:

```java
public void swapNames(int p, int q) {
    String temp = list.get(p);
    list.set(p, list.get(q));
    list.set(q, temp);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

Please read the basics of array and collection manipulation

### Assumption

Input will not contain duplicates

### Approach

1. Use indexOf to get the index of the elements
2. Remove both the elements (bigger index first and then smaller index)
3. First choose the lower index value and insert the replacement element
4. then insert the higher index value (ensure the check for size() if its last element)

### Solution

```java
  final String first = "chips"
  final String second = "plate"
  final int index1 = list.indexOf(first);
  final int index2 = list.indexOf(second);
  if (index1 < index2) {
    list.remove(index2);
    list.remove(index1);
    list.add(index1, second)
    if (index2 == list.size()) {
      list.add(first);
    } else {
      list.insert(index2, first);
    }
  } else {
    // do the reverse
  }
```